# Share in React native android not working on android 12 or later

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, share

Share working well for upto android 11, but after that i.e, from android 12 and onwards when clicked on the shared links it directly open to the webpage and says that is not available, what to do for solve it... my manifest.xml is

```
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                
                <data
                    android:host="www.app.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/app/" 
                    android:scheme="http"/>
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
```

and code for rereact native

```
        try {
            const result = await Share.share({
                message:
                    `http://www.app.com/app/${encryptId}`,
            });
            if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                } else {
                    // shared
                }
            } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                // dismissed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert(error.message);
        }
    };
```

Please help to solve it